# В CSS не повторяется svg изображение

Tags: css, svg

Как залить фон и почему код не работает?

**CSS:**

```
background: url("img/background.svg") repeat;
```

Comment: Проверьте с отдельный свойством background-repeat:repeat;

Comment: @Urmuz Tagizade он так тоже не повторяет
Пробовал png с инета вставлять, его репитит.
(https://www.gravatar.com/avatar/9bd620150717350f66401d7f9590a8b2?s=32&d=identicon&r=PG)

Comment: Аааа не обратил внимание на svg. Вам нужно указать <!DOCTYPE svg>

Comment: @Urmuz Tagizade, он так тоже не хочет

Comment: @soledar10, нет, так он тоже не хочет (

Comment: все работает,  размер вашего изображения  794 × 1123 pixels, по центру которого расположен паттерн, размером 130 × 130 , остальное прозрачный фон

Comment: @soledar10, Спасибо! Я исправил и теперь все работает, сейчас исправляю рисунок (наверное легче было бы самому все нарисовать)) =))
Напишите ответ, я чекну как правильный ответ.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Все работает, размер вашего изображения 794 × 1123 pixels, по центру которого расположен паттерн, размером 130 × 130 , остальное прозрачный фон